# Keyboard Shortcut "Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, shortcut

Trying to make a keyboard shortcut to reset a game. Earlier in the __init__ class I create a menu to start a new game, and use self.reset to reset the score/grid etc.
I now have been trying to implement the shortcut with the same command - the reset being a method within the class.

```
self._master.bind_all('<Control-n>', self.reset)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: reset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

My confusion is that the self.reset works fine earlier in the __init__ but then does not work for the shortcut?

I do not see how the shortcut is even giving any positional arguments to the method.

Now if I change it to self.reset() I get an error about the current class missing the _game attribute.

Here is the reset method:

```
def reset(self):
    self._game.get_default_score()
    self._game.reset()
    self._grid_view.draw(self._game.grid, self._game.find_connections())
```

Comment: can't make out what is `self._master` from code! Can you tell what is that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is easy - whatever the mechanism that binds the shortcut does, it is passing an extra parameter to your `reset` method.

Since you don't care what it is at all, just declare your method to accept
an extra optional parameter, and you should be good:

```
...
def reset(self, event=None):
    self._game.get_default_score()
    ...
```

So, searching for "bind_all" we find out your code actually uses tkinter, and what tkinter passe along to your method is the "event" - an object with information on what key whas actually pressed and such - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: I think your example would be better if you changed `extra` to `event`. Even though it may not be used, consistently using `event` in every binding will make the code easier to understand.

Comment: (done. I actually had answered it before confiming it was tkinter and the extra parameter was the "event" - the question is answerable in terms of "pure Python")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and the explanation! I had a feeling it may have been reading the Ctrl+N as an argument of some sort, hence why it worked in the other /__init__ command.