# Running a function on thread gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to run a function "generate_model" on thread which takes three arguments.

```
def thread_for_generate_model(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, job_id, boolean_string, Batch_size):
        self.name = name
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.boolean_string = boolean_string
        self.Batch_size = Batch_size

    def run(self):
        LOGGER.info("vector model create started for job_id: %s on thread %s", self.job_id, self.name)
        generate_model(self.job_id, self.boolean_string, self.Batch_size)
        LOGGER.info("vector model created for job_id: %s", self.job_id)

def main(): 
     ....
     thread_for_generate_model("Thread_for_vectormodel", job_id, generate_search_string(job_id,keywords), 5000).start()
     # I am trying to run this function on a thread
     # generate_model(job_id, generate_search_string(job_id,keywords), 5000)
     ....
```

I got an error ,

```
TypeError: thread_for_generate_model() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

by solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288364/keyboard-shortcut-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given), I have modified as below by adding an additional parameter

```
 def run(self, event=  None)
```

but still has the same error. how to rectify it?

Comment: There are a few things that you are not doing right - eg. `def thread_for_generate_model` should be - `class thread_for_generate_model`. Remember `def` is for defining functions where as `class` is for defining classes. I believe you are trying to define a class that inherits from `threading.Thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below should do what you are trying to do - I have just added a few dummy functions etc. to get the code not throw syntax error or undefined functions/variables etc.. This is roughly the structure you can follow.

As pointed out in the comments - use `def something` to define a method. and `class Something` to define a class.

```
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig()

class thread_for_generate_model(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, job_id, boolean_string, Batch_size):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.boolean_string = boolean_string
        self.Batch_size = Batch_size

    def run(self):
        LOGGER.info("vector model create started for job_id: %s on thread %s", self.job_id, self.name)
        generate_model(self.job_id, self.boolean_string, self.Batch_size)
        LOGGER.info("vector model created for job_id: %s", self.job_id)

def generate_search_string(job_id, keywords):
    return False

def generate_model(job_id, string, batch_size):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
def main():

    job_id = 0
    keywords = ['a', 'b']
    thread_for_generate_model("Thread_for_vectormodel", job_id, generate_search_string(job_id,keywords), 5000).start()
    # I am trying to run this function on a thread
    # generate_model(job_id, generate_search_string(job_id,keywords), 5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Got it thread should be of class.thanks for your comment,  it worked.